# Translating from SQL to Linq when having group by and order by

Tags: sql, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

is it possible to transform this sql code into linq?

```
SELECT top 3 t.tProductIDF, Count(t.tQty)as QtyBought, p.pName, v.vName
From Transactions t, Product p, Vendor v
where t.tProductIDF = p.pID and p.pdeleted = 0 and p.pVendorIDF = v.vID and v.vActive = 1
Group By t.tProductIDF, p.pName, v.vName
Order By QtyBought desc;
```

i am currently here:

```
var topProds = (from t in this._entities.Transactions
                group t by t.tProductIDF into g
                orderby g.Count() descending
                select new {g.Key }).Take(3);
```

but since i cannot access t  from the select part, i do not know how i can get pName and vName

Answer (score 1):

```
var topProds = (from t in this._entities.Transactions  
               group t by t.tProductIDF into g
               orderby g.Count() descending    
               select new { ProductIDF = g.Key , Qty= g.Sum(cc=>cc.tQty) , Vname = g.Select(cc=>cc.vName).FirstOrDefault() }).Take(3);
```

Your g hold each row in group.